# Dictionary only keeps the latest occurence if word appears multiple time in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Considering this list in a file:

```
1 fire
2 water
3 fire
4 earth
5 light
6 light
```

I'm trying to associate each word to its number so that I can let's say, ask for the word associated with 1 and it would be fire, but also ask for the word associated with 3 and it would return fire as well. Right now it completely forgets that 1 = fire, because it only remembers the last one which is 3 = fire. How should I approach this instead?

Here is my code:

```
with open(file, "r") as file:
    # Create a dictionary mapping each word to its corresponding number
    word_to_number = {word: int(num) for num, word in map(str.split, file)}
```

The dictionary only keeps the number associated to the last time the word appears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing, that's just how it works. What do you want to do? Do you want to keep track of all numbers that appear with same word?

Comment: What output were you expecting? Did you want the first time a value appeared rather than the last? Were you expecting a collection of all the positions where the value occurred? Or something else?

Comment: A Dictionary maps a key to a value; so by definition duplicate keys would not make sense. `num: word` would be allowed as your nums are unique.

Comment: I'm trying to associate each word to its number so that I can let's say, ask for the word associated with 1 and it would be fire, but also ask for the word associated with 3 and it would return fire as well. Right now it completely forgets that 1 = fire, because it only remembers the last one which is 3 = fire. How should I approach this instead?

Comment: Aha! Then what you're looking for is a dictionary with numbers as keys and words as values - exactly the opposite of what you're doing.

Comment: It feels really obvious now that you mention it yea, I guess I was just hoping there was a quick fix. I'll read on that, thank you!

Comment: You update you code to make a look up on the value after it's return So enter 3 [key] get value (fire). Then look up what keys have the value (fire) and return [1] (and [3] if necessary). If that's the kind of thing you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do can't easily be done in a comprehension.

You're looking for something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_to_number = defaultdict(list)
with open(file, "r") as file:
    for num, word in map(str.split, file):
       word_to_number[word].append(number)
```